Trying to find cointegrated pairs but getting false positives
Using statsmodels.tsa.stattools.coint to find cointegrated pairs of stock price time series but it seems to be returning a majority of false positives. Need ideas how to tune it to reduce the false positive rate.
nonStationInsts = []

for i in range(50):
    #find all non-stationary price series
    if adfuller(trainPrc[i])[1] > 0.05:
        nonStationInsts += [i]

critVal = 0.01

#Function used to find cointegrated pairs
def findCointPairs(critVal = 0.05):
    cointInsts = []
    for i in range(len(nonStationInsts)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nonStationInsts)):
            inst1 = nonStationInsts[i]
            inst2 = nonStationInsts[j]
            _, p, _ = coint(trainPrc[inst1], trainPrc[inst2])
            if p < critVal:
                cointInsts += [(inst1,inst2, max(p1,p2))]
    return cointInsts

The chart below shows the price and spread of a pair that the function found to be 'cointegrated' with a p value < 0.01 but visual inspection shows they are clearly diverging as time changes.


Did you specify the cointegrating vector to be (1,-1)? If not, the spread is not so interesting. Your graph would be more informative if it included the (hypothetically) stationary combination coming out of the (hypothetical) cointegrating relationship. Could you show that?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Edited to be more clear what help I was looking for

What about the questions I raised in my comment?
